# ColorBlend not found

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
```

then draw some text:

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
        ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
        GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
        HDC hdc;
        Font *fn = new Font(TEXT("Arial"),50);
        hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
        LinearGradientBrush *linGrBrush=new LinearGradientBrush(
            Point(0, 10),
            Point(200, 10),
            Color(255, 255, 0, 0),   
            Color(255, 0, 0, 255));

        Graphics *graphics=new Graphics(hdc);
         PointF drawPoint = PointF(150.0F,150.0F);
         SolidBrush* myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color::Black);
        graphics->DrawString(L"Test text",strlen("Test text"),fn,drawPoint,linGrBrush);
        GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

And had error that `ColorBlend` not found identifier,but seem all right. How I can fix it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the ColorBlend object anyway? You don't seem to be using it in that code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ColorBlend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Drawing2D.ColorBlend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class  is part of the .Net Framework, as far as I can tell there is nothing by that name in GDI+ for C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think the corresponding function in GDI+ is [LinearGradientBrush::SetInterpolationColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
As far as I understand the .NET documentation the InterpolationColors member in GDI+ is used here with this function.